# Converting JDATEw into a date format in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've created a query in Microsoft Access and one of my fields is to pull transaction dates. However when I run the query it's giving a date format like this 1170322, which is 03/22/2017. I'm trying to format it like this date (03/22/17) in order to select a specific date range I created on a front form of my database. I've tried the following, but I keep getting this message:

> datatype mismatch in criteria expression.

```
=DateValue((Left(Right("A",4),2) & "/" & Right("A",2) & "/" & Right(Left("A",3),2)))
```

Comment: Why is MySQL tagged? Are you connecting MS Access to it? If so, dates between two should align. If not, what data type is that as it is not date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are seriously mixing up *date values* and *formatted date values*. There is no way a query can return a date as 1170322 except if you apply a weird conversion of the date value to text.

Anyway, if you really do get such strings, and can't modify the query to return proper date values, the text output can be converted to date values like this:

```
TextDate = "1170322"
TrueDate = DateValue(Format(Right(TextDate, 6), "\2\0@@/@@/@@"))

' Returns: 2017-03-22
```

or in SQL:

```
TrueDate: DateValue(Format(Right([YourFieldTextDate],6),"\2\0@@/@@/@@"))
```

That value you can format for display as you like.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `format` function.

More information here: [Format Function with Dates](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php)

Comment: Dave, a link to some generic documentation doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's a fair point. I'll take that on board for any future answers.